# why cannot be updated data in database table using php?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my php code.In this code if the user edits his/her information and clicks the update button, the posted values must be updated in database side.My table name for user is users.But when I want to post some values just the name is updated not the others.And also the date is changed to 0000-00-00.Why does this happen?I couldn't understand.Any idea and reply will be helpful?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{

 include("db.php");

$name = $_POST['name'];

$password1 = md5($_POST['password1']);
$password2 = md5($_POST['password2']);
$date_of_birth = $_POST['date_of_birth'];
$place_of_birth = $_POST['place_of_birth'];
$info = $_POST['info'];
$nationality = $_POST['nationality'];

   echo $_POST['name'];
   echo $name;
   echo $date_of_birth;
   echo $info;
   echo $place_of_birth;
   echo $nationality;

if ($password1 != $password2) {
    include "src/header.php";
    include "src/mainmenu.php";
    echo '<p>Error: password does not match. Try again</a>';
    echo '<p><a href="EditProfile.php">Try again</p>';
    include "src/footer.php";
    exit;
}
//If the name and the other fields are empty
if($name=='' || $email=='' || $password1=='' || $password2=='' || $date_of_birth==       
    ''|| $place_of_birth==''|| $info=='' || $nationality=='' ){
    include "src/header.php";
    include "src/mainmenu.php";
    echo '<p>Error:You didn\'t fill the fields.Try again</a>';
    echo '<p><a href="EditProfile.php">Try again</p>';
    include "src/footer.php";
    exit;
}


   $email=$_SESSION['email'];

   $sql = "UPDATE users SET name='".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."',
                     info=     
   '".mysql_real_escape_string($info)."',

   password=".mysql_real_escape_string($password2)."'

   place_of_birth='".mysql_real_escape_string($place_of_birth)."',

   date_of_birth='".mysql_real_escape_string($date_of_birth)."', 

   nationality='".mysql_real_escape_string($nationality)."'
                     WHERE email ='$email'";


  $retval = mysql_query($sql,$link);



  if (!$retval|| $retval==false) {
    include "src/header.php";
    include "src/mainmenu.php";
    die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
    echo '<p><a href="EditProfile.php">Try again</a></p>';
    include "src/footer.php";
    mysql_close($link);
    exit;
}
else {
    echo "Updated data successfully\n";

    //header('Location: private.php');
}

  mysql_close($link);
  }
 else
 {
 include("db.php"); 

 $email=$_SESSION['email'];
 $run = mysql_query("select * from users where email='$email'") or die("Error!");
 $read = mysql_fetch_assoc($run);

 ?>
 <form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<fieldset>
<legend>Update Profile</legend>
<p>
    <label for="name">Full name:</label> <input type="text" name="name"     
 id="name" value="<?PHP echo $read['name']; ?>"/> 
<br>
    <label for="email">Email:</label> <input type="email" name="email"   
 id="email" value="<?PHP echo $read['email']; ?>"/> 
<br>
    <label for="password1">Password:</label> <input type="password"    
 name="password1" id="password1" />
<br>
    <label for="password2">Confirm password:</label> <input type="password"  
 name="password2" id="password2" />
<br>
    <label for="date_of_birth">Date of birth (yyyy-mm-dd):</label> <input  
type="date" name="date_of_birth" id="date_of_birth"  value="<?PHP echo 
$read['date_of_birth']; ?>"/>
<br>
    <label for="place_of_birth">Place of birth:</label> <input type="text"  
 name="place_of_birth" id="place_of_birth" value="<?PHP echo $read['place_of_birth']; ?
 >"/>
<br>
    <label for="info">Information:</label> <textarea name="info" id="info" 
rows="5" cols="50" ></textarea>
<br>
    <label for="nationality">Nationality:</label> <input type="text"    ,
name="nationality" id="nationality" value="<?PHP echo $read['nationality']; ?>"/>
</p>

<p class="center"><input value="Update" type="submit" name="update" id="update"/>  
 </p>
</fieldset>
</form>
<?php

}
?>
```

Comment: There's a lot of troubleshooting you could have done for this. Tell us what you've tried so far. I also don't think we need to see all of your code.

Comment: You missed one `,` after `...$password2)."'`

Comment: @JohnConde I tried to enter some values in the form for editing the user profile,  as you can there is an sql update code part in the code.But I cannot update the previous values in the related user entry.:(

Comment: @thinklinux I corrected it and wrote password='".mysql_real_escape_string($password2)."', and it works now.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code wrong in here;

```
password=".mysql_real_escape_string($password2)."'
```

change with this;

```
password='".mysql_real_escape_string($password2)."',
```

Answer (score 0):

When storing the `$date` in a `datetime` field in a MySQL database, you need to format it using the `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` format.

Comment: it was not related with it.In database the date is already in the type of Date.